# getScript multiple file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I am tring to use getScript() to load multiple file

```
<script>
     $(document).on('click', '.param-rule', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var id=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
         $.when(
             $.getScript( "{{ asset('admin/app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js') }}" ),
             $.getScript( "{{ asset('admin/app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.min.js') }}" ),
             $.getScript( "{{ asset('admin/app-assets/js/scripts/tables/datatables/datatable-basic.js') }}" ),
             $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
                 $( deferred.resolve );
             })
         ).done(function(){
             $('.param-content').load(Routing.generate('backlogrule_index', { id: id}), function() {
                 $(this).children(':first').unwrap();
             });
             $('.param-rule').addClass('active');
             $('.param').removeClass('active');
         });
     });


 </script>
```

If I click first  time on my button, the files do not load, but if I click a second time, the files will load.
First time => not datatable.
second time => datatable
Can you help me please

Comment: Why do you have these `{{ }}` in your `.getScript`? From what I've read online just leaving it as `$.getScript( "asset/admin/app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js" ),` should do the trick just fine....no?

Comment: Thank you JeanPaul but, I use twig Symfony. it's synthaxis. It returns the true path.

Comment: Have you tried putting the script in a `document.ready` function?

Comment: it does not work